# How to use .uniq with hashes for unique pairs?

Tags: ruby

Lets say I have an array with several hashes of emails and names.  For example I have something like this:

```
foo = [{id: 1, name: 'Eric Cartman', email: 'eric@southpark.com'},
       {id: 2, name: 'Eric Cartman', email: 'cartmanfamily@gmail.com'},
       {id: 3, name: "Cartman's mom", email: 'cartmanfamily@gmail.com'},
       {id: 4, name: 'Eric Cartman', email: 'eric@southpark.com'}]
```

How can I use `.uniq` to return unique values based on the combination of name and email?  For example I want to return something like this:

```
[{id: 1, name: 'Eric Cartman', email: 'eric@southpark.com'},
{id: 2, name: 'Eric Cartman', email: 'cartmanfamily@gmail.com'},
{id: 3, name: "Cartman's mom", email: 'cartmanfamily@gmail.com'}]
```

Comment: Fix the quotes, btw. Right now it's invalid ruby code and some people here _will_ object :)

Comment: You followed @Sergio's advice to fix the quotes but you still have a mix of single and double quotes. That offends my sensibilities, so I object!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foo.uniq` should work just fine.
Since

```
{name: "cartman", email: "cartman@sp.com"} == {name: "cartman", email: "cartman@sp.com"} # => True
{name: "stan", email: "stan@sp.com"} == {name: "cartman", email: "cartman@sp.com"} # => False
```

The `==` operator check if every field of the hash have the same values. So `.uniq` will work how you want it to work!

If there is more than only the email and name field you should use the `uniq` method with a block:

```
foo.uniq { |x| [x[:name], x[:email]] }
```

It will keep only the uniq combination of the name and email.

Hope it helped, happy ruby coding!

Comment: argh... I might have made my example too simple... What if there was an id in the has as well, so that foo would be this:
    `foo = [{id: 1, name: 'Eric Cartman', email: 'eric@southpark.com'},
       {id: 2, name: 'Eric Cartman', email: 'cartmanfamily@gmail.com'},
       {id: 3, name: "Cartman's mom", email: 'cartmanfamily@gmail.com'},
       {id: 4, name: 'Eric Cartman', email: 'eric@southpark.com'}]`

Comment: There's no need to announce edits in answers and the bold face is neither needed nor attractive. I suggest you simply rewrite your answer if you think of improvements or wish to implement suggestions made by others. Piling it onto to what you previously wrote is just a distraction. Write answers as you would a book or a blog, where revisions are normal.

Answer (score 1):

[`Array#uniq`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq) takes a block:

```
foo = [{id: 1, name: 'Eric Cartman', email: 'eric@southpark.com'},
       {id: 2, name: 'Eric Cartman', email: 'cartmanfamily@gmail.com'},
       {id: 3, name: "Cartman's mom", email: 'cartmanfamily@gmail.com'},
       {id: 4, name: 'Eric Cartman', email: 'eric@southpark.com'}]

bar = foo.uniq {|h| [h[:name], h[:email]] }

bar == [{id: 1, name: 'Eric Cartman', email: 'eric@southpark.com'},
        {id: 2, name: 'Eric Cartman', email: 'cartmanfamily@gmail.com'},
        {id: 3, name: "Cartman's mom", email: 'cartmanfamily@gmail.com'}] #=> true
```

Per the documentation, "If a block is given, it will use the return value of the block for comparison."